# Bootstrap buttons with glyphicon

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, button, glyphicons

```css
 .txt {
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .btnbtn {
   padding: 0px;
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .glyphbtn {
   padding-top: 4px;
   padding-bottom: 4px;
   padding-right: 7px;
   padding-left: 7px;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http:/ / maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com / bootstrap / 3.3.5 / js / bootstrap.min.js "></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a class="btn btn-default btnbtn " href="#">
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="txt"></asp:Label>
  <span class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphbtn"></span>
</a>
```

This is my code for my bootstrap button. The height of the glyphicon part of the button is not exact to the height of the whole button. The paddings and margins are all set to 0 already. I can't seem to figure out how to adjust its height to fit the whole button exactly. Please help thank you

Comment: you're having a button inside a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

padding-top and -bottom in class .btn need to be overwritten to 0px each; font needs to be increased until the overall button is returned to the previous size. In .glyphicon, top must be zeroed.  Finally, after viewing the page in firebug, there's a padding definition in the js file (padding-top:0 and -bottom:0) causing a sliver of space to remain.  It looks like your "js" css file defines a padding-top and -bottom property; when I removed these in Firebug, all remaining space was removed.  You might need to play around with the presence of !important on the padding-top and -bottom properties, meaning thoroughly overwrite the padding properties in their original classes if you don't use them.

```
.txt {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btnbtn {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.glyphbtn {
   padding-top: 4px;
   padding-bottom: 4px;
   padding-right: 7px;
   padding-left: 7px;
   text-align: center;
 }

.btn {
   padding-bottom: 0 !important;
   padding-top: 0 !important;
   font-size: 22px !important;
 }

.glyphicon {
   top: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do; set `padding: 0px !important;`

I was unable to see that in snippet, when i reproduce the error i don't see that much difference you added in image, there is one more little change required.

here is a link with more clear view.
[Link](http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/button.html)

```
 .btnbtn {
   padding: 0px !important;
 }

 .glyphbtn {
   top: 0px !important;
 }
```

Working example;

```css
 .txt {
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   text-align: center;
 }

 .btnbtn {
   padding: 0px !important;
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .glyphbtn {
   padding-top: 4px;
   padding-bottom: 4px;
   padding-right: 7px;
   padding-left: 7px;
   text-align: center;
   top: 0px !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a class="btn btn-default btnbtn " href="#">
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="txt"></asp:Label>
  <span class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphbtn"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: its working in code snippet, run code snippet n check

Comment: i edited the answer, saw your snapshot, reproduce the error, added a link at top in answer where you can see the final result